# Video chat SDK for android or iOS available?

Tags: android, ios, video

I'm looking to incorporate a video chat function in my android/iOS app, and I do not want to write that from scratch.

I was wondering if there's anything like the Multimedia SDK by Leadtools for Android/iOS. I tried googling but can't really find any component vendor that has it.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use video chat? Have you thought of a voice chat as a possible alternative. I found this on the web http://www.verious.com/component/telesocial-mobile-voice-to-mobile-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TokBox launched a SDK for iOS applications. It allows integrating their video chat platform into your existing applications without having to recreate any of the video chat functionality. I haven't tried it myself, but stumbled across their service in a similar search.

https://www.tokbox.com/live-video-ios-sdk

http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/21/tokbox-ios-sdk/

Sample app:

https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-iOS-Hello-World

Comment: Yeah. The tokbox sdk for iOS works nice except for some latency at times. But the Android version is still in beta and not working.

Answer (score -1):

**Video chat SDK for iOS or Android**

You can take a look at [Quickblox](https://quickblox.com) which allows to create text and video chats. You can find iOS and Android SDKs. They have a free plan for checking if it is fit you